# ArrayList<pojo> is creating null arrays in a list when printed with Jackson Object Mapper

Tags: java, arraylist, jackson2

I'm trying to read a delimited file, map that to pojo, creating an Array List of that POJO object and printing that. But looks like ArrayList is creating null arrays in the list when printed with Jackson 2 Object Mapper.

1. Please find the code snippet:

```
package ftp.service;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import com.adac.ftp.model.Tax;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;


@WebService
public class FTPDataExtractService {

    @WebMethod
    public void ftpDataExtractMethod() throws IOException {

        File source = new File("D:/RAW_DATA.zip");
        String out = "D:/Unzipped";

        unzip(source, out);

        try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("D:/Unzipped"))) {

            List<String> result = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(result);
            List<Tax> taxList = new ArrayList<Tax>();



            result.forEach((n) -> {

                String path = n;

                try { 

                    String line = "";
                    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(path);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));




                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] row = line.split("\\|");



                             if (path.contains("TRANSACTION_FLIGHT")) {

                                 Tax tax = new Tax(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);

                                   taxList.add(tax); 


                             }

                        }
                    ObjectMapper req_mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    req_mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
                    String json_req = req_mapper.writeValueAsString(taxList);   
                    System.out.println(json_req); 

                    reader.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Collection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Collection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            });
        }

    }



    public static void unzip(File source, String out) throws IOException {
        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(source))) {

            ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();

            while (entry != null) {

                File file = new File(out, entry.getName());

                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    file.mkdirs();
                } else {
                    File parent = file.getParentFile();

                    if (!parent.exists()) {
                        parent.mkdirs();
                    }

                    try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[Math.toIntExact(entry.getSize())];

                        int location;

                        while ((location = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            bos.write(buffer, 0, location);
                        }
                    }
                }
                entry = zis.getNextEntry();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. The File is getting read is below:

```
10797|SRF002|AD4|SIAD104120619017|WY 0634|MCT|2019-06-11|||Y|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308110619028|EY 0278|MLE|2019-06-10|||J|A
10797|SRF002|AD5|SIAD105120619013|EY 0226|AMD|2019-06-11|||Y|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308110619020|EY 0101|JFK|2019-06-10|||J|A
10797|SRF002|AD4|SIAD104110619015|ME 0419|BEY|2019-06-10|||Y|A
10797|SRF002|AD4|SIAD104120619007|MS 0917|CAI|2019-06-11|||Y|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308120619059|EY 0333|JED|2019-06-11|||Y|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308110619027|EY 0472|CGK|2019-06-10|||J|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308120619063|EY 0025|LHR|2019-06-11|||Y|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308100619067|EY 0315|RUH|2019-06-10|||J|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308120619058|EY 0653|CAI|2019-06-11|||Y|A
10797|SRF002|AD5|SIAD105110619027|6E 1834|BOM|2019-06-10|||Y|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308110619046|EY 0282|COK|2019-06-10|||Y|A
10797|SRF002|AD5|SIAD105110619031|EY 0424|MNL|2019-06-11|||Y|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308110619061|EY 0005|MUC|2019-06-11|||Y|A
10797|SRF002|AD4|SIAD104100619024|EY 0233|ISB|2019-06-09|||Y|A
10797|SRF003|AD8|SIAD308120619030|EY 0019|LHR|2019-06-11|||Y|A
10797|SRF002|AD4|SIAD104100619021|EY 0653|CAI|2019-06-09|||Y|A
10797|SRF002|AD5|SIAD105100619011|EY 0317|RUH|2019-06-09|||Y|A
10797|SRF002|AD4|SIAD104120619020|RJ 0621|AMM|2019-06-11|||Y|A
```

3. The console print is below:

```
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ {
  "taxid" : "10797",
  "taxamount" : "SRF002",
  "currency" : "AD4",
  "taxbaseamount" : "SIAD104120619017",
  "taxexcgrate" : "WY 0634",
  "taxexcgdate" : "MCT",
  "taxexcgtype" : "2019-06-11"
}, {
  "taxid" : "10797",
  "taxamount" : "SRF003",
  "currency" : "AD8",
  "taxbaseamount" : "SIAD308110619028",
  "taxexcgrate" : "EY 0278",
  "taxexcgdate" : "MLE",
  "taxexcgtype" : "2019-06-10"
}, {
  "taxid" : "10797",
  "taxamount" : "SRF002",
  "currency" : "AD5",
  "taxbaseamount" : "SIAD105120619013",
  "taxexcgrate" : "EY 0226",
  "taxexcgdate" : "AMD",
  "taxexcgtype" : "2019-06-11"
}, {
  "taxid" : "10797",
  "taxamount" : "SRF003",
  "currency" : "AD8",
  "taxbaseamount" : "SIAD308110619020",
  "taxexcgrate" : "EY 0101",
  "taxexcgdate" : "JFK",
  "taxexcgtype" : "2019-06-10"
}, {
  "taxid" : "10797",
  "taxamount" : "SRF002",
  "currency" : "AD4",
  "taxbaseamount" : "SIAD104110619015",
  "taxexcgrate" : "ME 0419",
  "taxexcgdate" : "BEY",
  "taxexcgtype" : "2019-06-10"
}, {
  "taxid" : "10797",
  "taxamount" : "SRF002",
  "currency" : "AD4",
  "taxbaseamount" : "SIAD104120619007",
  "taxexcgrate" : "MS 0917",
  "taxexcgdate" : "CAI",
  "taxexcgtype" : "2019-06-11"
}, {
  "taxid" : "10797",
  "taxamount" : "SRF003",
  "currency" : "AD8",
  "taxbaseamount" : "SIAD308120619059",
  "taxexcgrate" : "EY 0333",
  "taxexcgdate" : "JED",
  "taxexcgtype" : "2019-06-11"
}, {
  "taxid" : "10797",
  "taxamount" : "SRF003",
  "currency" : "AD8",
  "taxbaseamount" : "SIAD308110619027",
  "taxexcgrate" : "EY 0472",
  "taxexcgdate" : "CGK",
  "taxexcgtype" : "2019-06-10"
}
------------------<more data here as per the delimited file>-----
]
```

I'm not getting why this is printing 4 blank arrays "[]" at the beginning? Am I doing any silly mistake?

Comment: You're reading all the files in a directory. Some of the files don't have TRANSACTION_FLIGHT in their name, so your code generates an empty list for those files, and prints it.

Comment: Right. It's a silly mistake I did. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I good understand your code you want read data from many files in given directory and put it in Array.

You should use `ObjectMapper` after all files will be readed. So put it after `result.forEach((n) -> { .. }`